# Integration with cuhre

Tags: r, numerical-integration

I am using cuhre from R2Cuba 1.1-0 for integrating the following function

```
fn <- function(x) { 
        pnorm((-2-sum(sqrt(vecRho)*x))/sqrt(1-sum(vecRho)))*prod(dnorm(x))
      }
```

where *vecRho* is a vector of 6 numbers between 0 and 0.1, i.e.

```
vecRho<-runif(6,0,0.1)
```

By definition, the integrand *fn* is between 0 and 1. The integration is expected to be positive. However, using *cuhre* the result becomes negative when the length of *vecRho* exceeds 5.

```
NDIM<-length(vecRho) 
cuhre(NDIM, 1, fn, 
      flags = list(verbose =0),
      lower = rep(-10,NDIM),
      upper = rep(10,NDIM))$value
[1] -0.4738284
```

Moreover, when the length of *vecRho* >=6 the absolute value of the integration increases as the length of *vecRho* increases.

Is there something I can do to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: It is unclear what's the meaning of `prod(dnorm(x))`. Do you really need PRODUCT of all gaussian kernels?

Comment: Yes, prod(dnorm(x)) is the density function. Since all the variables are independent, the density of n-dim variate normal distribution is effectively the product of dnorm(x).

Answer (score 0):

ok, got it, you have 6D integral with 6 gaussian kernels inside. I know good answer for 1D integration with gaussian kernel. It is called [Gauss-Hermite quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Hermite_quadrature), and there is an **R** package for that. If you go this route, you'll have to
make curry functions, but it might worth it.

Some sample code:

```
library(gaussquad)

n.quad <- 128 # integration order

# get the particular (weights,abscissas) as data frame
# with 2 observables and n.quad observations
rule <- ghermite.h.quadrature.rules(n.quad, mu = 0.0)[[n.quad]]

# test function - integrate 1 over exp(-x^2) from -Inf to Inf
# should get sqrt(pi) as an answer
f <- function(x) {
    1.0
}

q <- ghermite.h.quadrature(f, rule)
print(q - sqrt(pi))
```

Comment: Thanks, Severin. I think using currying function approach will work. In fact, it  works just using "integrate" function in r. The issue is run-time. It is very time consuming even with D=3. I wonder how "gaussquad" performs when D>=3.

Comment: @Loy Well, each integration is weighted sum of 128 (in case above) calls to `f`. So 6D integral would be 128^6 calls. I prefer G-H (or Gauss-Legendre in case of exponential kernel) because it takes care of values under the gaussian bell better than anything else

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Severin. Will give it a try.